# So im trying to make a reaction trigger for my bot.The run down is Whenever your message has "sus" in it, the bot would reacted with the sus emote

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is my code so far:

```py
@bot.event() 
async def  on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user,):
    if 'sus' in message.content:
        on_reaction_add(":sus:")
```

And it's telling me this in terminal:

> TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

what do I do??

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, but please stop copy pasting code from somewhere else without understanding it. I would suggest you to learn python first.

with that being said, your error is because you have added `()` for event. It's only `@bot.event` not `@bot.event()`

`on_reaction_add` is an event for when someone adds a reaction. `message` is non-existent. `self` is to be used in a cog, if it's in a Cog, you would have to use `@commands.Cog.listener()` not `@bot.event`

use an `on_message` event for your purpose

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.author.bot:
           return
     if "sus" in message.content.lower():
          await message.add_reaction("the emote")

# Note the emote needs to be in a form <:name:ID> or else it won't work
# your bot also needs to be in the server in which the "sus" emote is
```

Comment: returning almost 1 year later to say, Thank you.